# How do you and should you move event bus functionality to Vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Right now I'm using an event bus to call methods of certain Vue components from other non-related Vue components.

I have a functioning Vuex store, so I'm trying to get rid of the event bus and move this functionality to Vuex store.

### Questions

- Should I move event bus functionality to Vuex store or should I use both?
- What's the best way to implement event bus functionality in a Vuex store?
- Could you please give an actual example of how to call a method inside another non-related component using Vuex:

#### First.vue

```
methods: {
  test1 () {
    console.log('test1 was called')
  }
}
```

#### Second.vue

```
methods: {
  callMethodInsideFirstComponent () {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a need for an event bus, there's no harm in using one. The main problems people have with them are **1)** that they pollute the global event space (obviously), **2)** if relied upon too heavily can become cumbersome to track, and **3)** risk collisions with event names or unintended side effects.

Vuex is a shared reactive state accessible anywhere throughout your application. Key word being reactive, don't think you will be calling methods between components, i.e. component A calls a method defined in component B. Instead, component A will mutate a given property in the state tree which component B is observing (typically in a computed property or watcher).

For example:

```
// First.vue
<template>
   <div>{{ myStoreProp }}</div>
</template>
...
computed: {
    myStoreProp () {
        return this.$store.getters['myModule/myStoreProp']
    }
}

// Second.vue
<template>
    <button @click="updateMyStoreProp('Hello from Second.vue')">Click Me</button>
</template>
...
methods: {
   updateMyStoreProp (value) {
       this.$store.commit('myModule/myStoreProp', value)
   }
}
```

Now whenever Second.vue calls it's `updateMyStoreProp` function, the value committed to the store will reflect in First.vue's template, in this case printing "Hello from Second.vue".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to be able to call methods, not to update a property. Let's say there's a big method in my `First.vue`, I want to be able to pass the arguments and call it from `Second.vue` so I don't have to copy that big method to each component, can I do that via Vuex store, or I have to use event bus?

Comment: Yes, you just need to look at it from a different angle. All the data that you pass to the method can be written to the store instead of passed as argument(s). Then you can "trigger" the other components method using a watcher. Once triggered, the method then reads the data out of the store and does it's thing.

Comment: However, this leads up to store actions, which is ideally where you should have this method and you can then dispatch calls to the action from any component that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event bus to emit and listen event, but you should use vuex when your app become complex. Use vuex API `subscribe` to implement event bus functionality using vuex. https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe

Just simple step, you commit `mutation` in component A, and use `subscribe` to listen mutation in component B.

Comment: Please provide an example of how to call component's B methods from component A using `subscribe`